# What do <div class="masthead pdng-stn1"> and <div class="phone-box wrap push" id="home"> mean?

Tags: javascript, css

I am applying the css into my web pages, and using bootstrap, but I found that a sentences described as the title, I don't understand the meaning of "masthead pdng-stn1" and the meaning of "phone-box". I can't find the definition of them in the bootstrap.css and all of the css files in my folders, but they can't be deleted otherwise the web pages can't display properly.

Answer (score 2):

Generally "classes" are just a way to group/categorize elements on a page and apply like-styles to them. `pdng-stn1` is clearly a poorly thought out name, and whatever it means would have made more semantic sense, like `pudding-stain1` or whatever. They're not necessarily related to Bootstrap in any way. `masthead` is often synonymous with `header` or `page-top`, something like that. You really just need to dive through the source code, or read the documentation that comes with whatever frameworks your website is using.

If you'd like you can read up on the basics of [CSS Class Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). They're essentially entirely arbitrary and are chosen based on the current developer's needs and desires for structure, or for integration/semantic similarity with the current framework.